# Adding glare causes screen glitches

Tags: error, compositing-nodes

what it looks like with glare:

[image]

what it looks like without glare:

[image]

This seems like the easiest thing to solve but I haven't found any documentation of this problem on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T77314), this is a bug that has been around since 2.8 when using NLM denoising.

A description from the report:

> Glare node bug when using NLM denoising
>
> [...]
>
> Occasionally noisy when using grain anodes in compositor particle
> images. No issue with OIDN.

So it is best to use **OpenImageDenoise instead of NLM** for denoising to work around this.

If that is not an option, other denoisers might work; or higher sample numbers and different render seeds for single frames.